# Python: When running a for loop, how to append each solution to a list, which is appended to a new dictionary?

Tags: python, numpy

So if I've got any trivial function, e.g.:

```
def summation_ind(a,b):
          summation = 2*a + 3*b
          if summation < 4:
              return True
          else:
              return False
```

And a and b come from a list of numbers, and I have a for loop such as:

```
newdict = {}
newlist = []
for a in R:
          for b in R:
              if summation(a,b):
                  newlist.append((a,b))
newdict['numbs']=set(newlist)
```

How do I do it so that every time the loop runs, a and b are appended to a new list and the new list is appended to a new dictionary? In other words, if there are 15 combinations of a,b values that work with the algorithm, is there any way to create 15 new lists in 15 new dictionaries? Is that possible?

Thank you :)

Comment: appended to a new list or appended to `newlist`?

Comment: Incidentally, you could write `def summation_ind(a,b): return 2*a + 3*b < 4`

Comment: i am not sure why `a` and `b` are both coming from `R`, but im sure you have a reason.

Comment: @InbarRose It has to do with the logistics of the game I'm creating, no reason other than that.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary appended to a new list. Not newlist.

Comment: independently from the question, since I am certain `R` is a 1-d array, you should vectorize this, such as `2*R + 3*R[:,None] < 4`.

Comment: "is there any way to create 15 new lists in 15 new dictionaries? Is that possible?" yes - but you will put them into a bigger dictionary, so you will have `dict[subdict_identifier][inner_key] = list()` but this is not a good approach, i think you should read more about data collections, like dictionaries, and see what exactly they are, i do not think you are using them correctly. it seems to me that you are new to python and possibly to programming as well, instead of trying to fit your ideas into something you know, just ask and those of us that understand can tell you where to put them.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to make it simpler.

using a set in your dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dictionary = defaultdict(set)

for a, b in ((a, b) for a in R for b in R):
    if summation(a, b):
        dictionary['numbs'].add((a,b))
```

using a list in your dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dictionary = defaultdict(list)

for a, b in ((a, b) for a in R for b in R):
    if summation(a, b):
        dictionary['numbs'].append([a,b])
```

or even using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
dictionary['numbs'] = [(a, b) for a in R for b in R if summation(a, b)]
```

Comment: `set` requires hashable types, so use `(a,b)` instead of `[a,b]`.

Comment: @InbarRose thanks for your help, but I need it to create a _new_ list and a consequent new dictionary every time the code runs - so for every a,b combination.

Comment: @Amanc I don't understand. you want to perform `summation` on every `a, b` combination. and then you want to put the values of `a, b` into a list - and then put that list into a new dictionary? this is very wasteful. what exactly is this accomplishing? you will have potentially hundreds of dictionaries each with only a single key, each key with only a single list as the value, and the list with only a single item? why not just put it will in a single list of each item? or a dictionary where the key is the `a, b` pair, and the value is either `True` or `False` based on `summation`?

Comment: @InbarRose the functions I put in this thread are not the same functions I will be using in the code - I will need to use a code like this many times, actually - e.g. if I am modelling a population, each time an infected person touches another person I want them to be a list, as I also have a function for joining two 'lists' of people touching each other. I do need this for my code to work. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @Amanc I may be wrong - but it almost sounds like you should be looking at a `graph`

Comment: @JonClements actually, when I did this in java years ago it ended up producing a graph. Im trying to recreate it in python, and having difficulties as I'm quite inexperienced :P. The idea is to eventually have a visual representation of what is happening as I'm coding a model. This is the rough outline.

Comment: @Amanc you need to be more clear in your question, else you can not be helped. this is the second time today i am answering one of your questions, and each time you are revealing information only after i have answered what you posted. you have 3 choices how i see it, either be open and full towards SO and let us help you fully, no sudden revelations or secrecy (within reason) or do it all yourself, and instead of asking for help, research and study on your own. and lastly, post very specific questions where you explicitly explain input/desired output. i want to help, but you make it hard.

Comment: @InbarRose very sorry for this, I don't mean to make it difficult. I didn't think you'd need to know what I need it for - just that I need to be able to do it - but next time I'll include everything. Thanks.